# Probability of Linear Combinations

Tags: probability

This is from Ch. 6 of Modern Mathematical Statistics.

> A concert has three pieces of music to be played before intermission. The time taken to play each piece has a normal distribution. Assume that the three times are independent of each other. The mean times are 15, 30 and 20min respectively and the standard deviations are 1, 2 and 1.5min respectively. What is the probability that this part of the concert takes at most 1hr?

My approach:

$E[Y]=E[X_1+X_2+X_3]=E[X_1]+E[X_2]+E[X_3]=15+30+20=65\\
\sigma[Y]=\sigma(X_1)+\sigma(X_2)+\sigma(X_3)=1+2+1.5=4.5\\
Then\;P(Y\le60)=P(Z\le\frac{(60-65)}{4.5})=\phi(-1.11)=1-\phi(1.11)=0.1335$

However, this answer is incorrect. Where is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

You can add the variances only if the random variables are independent, not the standard deviations. Thus the variance is $Var(Y)=1^2+2^2+1.5^2$

Comment: Ah, such a silly mistake. Thanks.

Comment: @Caerus It´s all right as long you don´t make the same mistake in the future. You´re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You should be adding the variances to get the overall variance, then taking the square root to get the standard deviation.